# Memory pointlessly allocated with ARC

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, xcode-instruments

I'm observing iTunes using the `NSDistributedNotificationCenter` class.
This method is called when iTunes plays a new track. The implementation is empty.

Strangely, when I have ARC enabled, there is some memory allocated every time this method `observeITunes:` method gets called. Apparently, this memory is never released.

[image]

No matter how long I wait, this memory is never released.

So I found this strange and made an empty test-project, copying the relevant code there.
In the test-project there is no memory allocation visible at all (Which is correct).

---

## Code

```
[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                    selector:@selector(observeITunes:)
                                                        name:@"com.apple.iTunes.playerInfo"
                                                      object:nil];

- (void)observeITunes:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // Empty method
}
```

---

Can anyone explain this phenomenon to me?
I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Use the 'mark heap' feature of Instruments to mark the points in time when this empty method would theoretically execute, then examine the new allocation types for each heap.

Comment: @bneely How do I do that? Sorry, I don't have a lot of experience with Instruments.

Comment: Here's a link to Apple documentation and a screenshot of Instruments showing the Mark Heap button: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AnalysisTools/Reference/Instruments_User_Reference/AllocationsInstrument/AllocationsInstrument.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011355-CH40-SW10 . You use the Allocations instrument, then press Mark Heap at significant events while running your app. Then you can examine changes between marked heaps and get a list of new allocations.

Comment: How many observers do you add?

Comment: @HotLicks Just that one

Comment: And only once?  `addObserver` isn't inside the loop?

Comment: @HotLicks Which loop? No it's called once in `init`

Comment: The loop created by cycling through the tunes.

Comment: @HotLicks No I just use iTunes to skip through the tracks.

Comment: So `addObserver` is only called once, for the entire app?  And iTunes isn't caching anything?

Comment: @HotLicks Yes. I'm not sure what it should cache. It's a simple notification.